# Creating a data model that accepts all key value pairs

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, swagger, data-modeling

I have a Web API Controller that contains a post command such as this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]UserProfile value)
    {
       ...
    }
```

This is what my UserProfile class looks like:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

If the client sends a post request that looks like the following, I want to be able to also deserialize the extra fields. Is there a way I can dynamically create these fields in my data model?

```
{
    "userId": "a123",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "...": "..."
}
```

I want to be able to accept (at the very least) userId and email, but if the user sends me more data, I'd like to accept that as well in order to store it into a NoSQL database.

I can probably just change my object from UserProfile to Dictionary, but I want my swagger documentation to show UserId and Email.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can dynamically create these fields in my data model?

One solution I can think of is to accept a dictionary which will accommodate any number of key-value pairs like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]IDictionary<string, string> pairs)
{
   ...
}
```

You can get the `UserId` and `Email` from the dictionary and if there are more items then you can process those as well.

The other thing you can do is try and think of all the possible properties the object can have and make most of them optional, then in your controller, check if they have values and process them.